# Survival Analysis in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, survival-analysis

I have been using standard packages for survival analysis in R. I know how to do classification problems in TensorFlow such as logistic regression, but I am having difficulty mapping this to survival analysis problems. In a way, instead of one output vector you have two (time_to_event::continuous, censored::boolean). This has been done in Theano, [here](https://github.com/jaredleekatzman/DeepSurv/blob/master/deepsurv/deep_surv.py), but I am having difficulty translating this to TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a logistic regression to do the survival analysis, however, another way you can use TensorFlow is to have the tf model predict the parameters of a survival distribution. So if you used the Weibull distribution you could, instead of regressing onto the time to event and a censoring probability, estimate the characteristic life (alpha parameter) and the shape (beta parameter). That is, the tf model estimates the parameters of the survival distribution directly.

The loss function can be the maximum likelihood which means you can incorporate observed and censored data.